# Iron in FTB Infinity Evolved Skyblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My buddy and I started playing this last night and after crafting our first expert mode bucket, we were pretty fed up with how slow it was getting iron from sieving gravel.

Is there a better way of getting iron or somehow automating the sieve?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get an [Autonomous Activator](http://ftbwiki.org/Autonomous_Activator).  Eventually you can start piping in the sand and out the resources...